# Posting the value of a drop down menu to a PHP page via a HTML form

Tags: php, html, mysql, forms

I'm creating a form in HTML which sends the question a user is asking, and the topic which the question should appear under to a PHP page. The topic names are pulled from a MySQL database using PHP.

I want to post the value of the drop down menu (the topic that the user has chosen) along with a HTML form to a PHP page. Here is my form code:

```html
<form action="add_question.php" method="post">
  Question:<input name="question_text" type="question"><br>

  <select name="topic_name">
    <option>Topic</option>
      <?php
        // Get each topic name from the database
        include "connect_database.php";

        $topicQuery = "SELECT topic_name FROM topics
                       ORDER BY topic_name";

        $result = $conn->query($topicQuery);

        if ($result->num_rows > 0)
        {
          while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
          {
            // Make topic an option in drop down box
            echo '<option>' . $row["topic_name"] . '</option>';
          }
        }

        // Close connection
        mysqli_close($conn);
      ?>
  </select><br>

  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

When this is posted to **add_question.php**, $_POST['topic_name'] has no value. I think there's a problem with my form, although I can't see what. Any help would be great.

Thanks!

Comment: You say `$_POST['topic_name']` has no value, but you don't actually use it anywhere in your code. Why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to assign a value to your options like :

```
 echo '<option value='.$row["topic_id"].'>' . $row["topic_name"] . '</option>';
```

**Note:** `topic_id` an exmaple of a value you may use any other value

Comment: That makes sense, I don't know why I didn't see that I wasn't actually assigning a value to the option being posted. I haven't had a chance to try this yet, but I'm sure it'll work. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You need to add value attribute to all your options

```
<option value="some value">some value</option>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<form action="add_question.php" method="post">
  Question:<input name="question_text" type="question"><br>

  <select name="topic_name">
    <option>Topic</option>
      <?php
        // Get each topic name from the database
        include "connect_database.php";

        $topicQuery = "SELECT topic_name FROM topics
                       ORDER BY topic_name";

        $result = $conn->query($topicQuery);

        if ($result->num_rows > 0)
        {
          while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
          { ?>

           <option value="<?=$row["topic_name"]?>"><?=$row["topic_name"]?></option>

            <?php
          }
        }

        // Close connection
        mysqli_close($conn);
      ?>
  </select><br>

  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
<form action="add_question.php" method="POST">
    Question: <input name="question_text" type="question"><br/>
    <select name="topic_name">
        <option>Topic 1</option>
        <option>Topic 2</option>
        <option>Topic 3</option>
    </select>
    <input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

Note that you don't need a value as mentioned above and you are going to fill your options using your database of course. And notice the input type="submit".

Then on the page add_question.php do the following:

```
echo $_POST["question_text"];
echo "<br/>";
echo $_POST["topic_name"];
```

That prints out the correct items when I use it.